# Imperfect circular orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, precession

At Arnold's classical mechanics [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pd8-s6rOt_cC) on page 40 he introduced the following problem:

> PROBLEM. At the entry of a satellite into a circular orbit at a distance 300 km  from the earth the direction of its velocity deviates from the intended direction by 1 o towards the earth. How is the perigee changed?

1. How does the motion look like in compare to regular circular orbit?
2. The hint Arnold gives on second order, Whose second order?
3. How to derive the equation of motion?
4. I was wondering how Einstein's GR would solve such problem.

Comment: Do you mean 1 degree, and also I feel this is a very broad question, maybe you would consider  sticking to the first question and show what you have done. Using GR would be using a hammer to crack an egg, imo

Comment: @CountTo10 neither a small nor intuitive egg also in the classical case.

Comment: Please ignore the title of the website, it's a  dreadful name imo ,  but it has the basic satellite equations, if you already know them well,  (I don't ) then I'm sorry :http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circles/Lesson-4/Mathematics-of-Satellite-Motion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the orbit can be assumed to be a Kepler orbit, then rotating the velocity in the radial direction (without changing its magnitude) will make the orbit more elliptical. Note that it does not matter if you rotate a way or towards the Earth. The orbital eccentricity can be calculated with,

$$
e = \sqrt{1 + \frac{v_\theta^2 r}{\mu} \left(\frac{v^2 r}{\mu} - 2\right)}, \tag{1}
$$

with $v_\theta$ the magnitude of the tangential component of the velocity, $r$ the magnitude of the position of the satellite relative to the center of mass of the Earth, $\mu$ the gravitational parameter of the Earth and $v$ the magnitude of the total velocity.

For a circular orbit the velocity points completely in the tangential direction. So if the velocity is rotated by an angle $\alpha$ in the radial direction, then the tangential velocity can be expressed as,

$$
v_\theta = v \cos(\alpha). \tag{2}
$$

The relation between the periapsis and eccentricity is,

$$
r_p = (1-e) a, \tag{3}
$$

with $a$ the semi-major axis of the orbit, which stays constant since the orbital energy does not change.

This should be enough to help you solve this. But remember that the initial orbit of 300 km is the altitude above the surface of the Earth.

Comment: What are the conditions for precession?

Comment: @0x90 What do you mean by that, in context of your question/my answer?

Comment: Yes, under what terms there will be a precession? Higher angle/speed etc.

Comment: @0x90 Precession occurs when the gravitational field is not completely spherical symmetric. For example the Earth bulges at its equator, due to its own rotation. I do have to note that this is [nodal precession](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_precession). You also have [apsidal precession](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsidal_precession).